# Get File path from binary data

Tags: python, file, odoo

Is it possible to get the path of a file from binary data?

I have only binary data which came from reading the file, but have no information of file path.

Does the binary data have the information of path? if yes then How can I get it.

I need to read xlsx file using python xlrd lib, which requires the file path, 
but i only have binary data.

Can anyone shed light on it?

Comment: yes, I have binary content.

Comment: Let's put it differently, since I do not know what kind of files we are talking about: Will that "binary data" _change_, when you move the file around, to a different directory, or rename it?

Comment: The closest you can get is a list of **all** files with that binary content, found by comparing your binary data with that of every file on your filesystem, which would take a considerable amount of time.

Comment: I need to use xlrd lib to read the xlsx files, but it requires the file path to read the data from it.but i have only binary data.

Comment: How comes you do not have the file path in the first place? Have you tried writing the binary data to some temporary file and using the path of that file as input to the library?

Comment: @tobias_k No, I have not wrote the file. I am using OpenERP's binary widget. when i read the value it gives me the binary data.

Comment: I do not know this framework, but try the following: Dump your binary data to _any_ file, and feed that file into you xlrd lib.

Comment: @tobias_k  Yes I can do that way!! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I think this question is not that far-fetched, and others might come up with similar questions, so I just posted this as an answer. Maybe it helps someone else, too. :-)

Comment: https://www.openerp.com/apps/6.0/web_gallery/    check this module and port it to version 7 this will help you to store file in local path instead of binary so you can get file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Done this before like,

```
def read_file(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not context: context = {}
    rec = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context)
    file_path = tempfile.gettempdir()+'/file.xlsx'
    data = rec.file
    f = open(file_path,'wb')
    f.write(data.decode('base64'))
    f.close()
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
    ....
```

Then you can do your process.

Comment: Basically what I suggested, but with framework-specific code added. +1

Comment: @tobias_k exactly, by reading your comments I recalled that "yes, I have done this before". Thanks for recalling!

Answer (score 1):

Generally there's no way to retrieve the path of a file just from it's content. There may be file formats for which this is possible, but in the general case there is no way.

However, if you need the file's path only to feed the file into some other part of your program, there is another way: Just dump your binary data into *any* file (or temp file), and use that file's path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the binary data from a stream, then there is **NO** way of getting the file path.

If you think about it, the data may also be coming through stdin or through a network socket, so no file path is associated with it.

A possible approach is to manipulate the program to attach file path information along with the binary stream. We can help more in this approach, if you can post the code of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think what you are doing to right. IfIf you have the binary data in your database, then create a buffer using the python [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) package, then load the binary file to the buffer. Then do whatever you want