# How to import file on openerp 7?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I tried to import file to openerp 7 and I use the field `binary` but it doesn't give me the name of the file, just the content binary.

How can I recover the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Your Python model:

```
'source_file': fields.binary('Your binary file'),
'filename': fields.char('Filename'),
```

Your XML view:

```
<field name="filename" invisible="1"/>
<field name="source_file" filename="filename"/>
```

And this way you will have the file name stored in the variable `filename`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem is not totally solved. I need the complete path, but variable "filename" return just the filename

Comment: Ok, you should specify that in your question. If you need the whole path, then this could help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458155/get-file-path-from-binary-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458155/get-file-path-from-binary-data)

Comment: You're welcome @HaroldLarson. Please, don't forget to set the answer as correct to close the question, if you consider this one solved your problem.