# how to get the path of binary when call method

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

Hello EveryOne I want to get path of file imported 
this field declared like this

```
attachment_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', string='Files')
file = fields.Binary('file',string='file')
@api.multi
def get_path_file(self):
    path =""
    path = pathof(self.file)# here i want to get the path
    shutil.copy2(path+name_of_file, '/desktop/folder_copy')
```

in onchange or any method when i make a breakpoint i want to get path like this

**( /home/Desktop/backup/files/myfile.pdf)**

Comment: please elaborate your issue. we get nothing out of what you posted

Comment: i fix it now check the question

Comment: could you please print the type of `self.file`. `print(type(self.file))`

Comment: he shows to me this <class 'odoo.api.ir.attachment'>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get File path from binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458155/get-file-path-from-binary-data)

Answer (score 0):

To Get the **Absolute path** you can try this way,

```
import os
dir_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
relative_path = "data/text_file.txt"
absolute_path = os.path.join(dir_name, relative_path)
```

Thanks